# How to change dynamic the value of dictionary with a for in loop in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, for-loop

```
func answersAndResults(answerIndex: Int, link: Dictionary <Int, Int>) {
    if inputIndex == answerIndex {
        for (linkedResult, weight) in link {
            linkedResult += weight // Left side of mutating operator isn't immutable: "linkedResul" is a let costant
        }            
    }
}
```

How I can change dynamic the values of the of dictionary with a for in loop?

Comment: Unrelated but you need to learn to use proper naming conventions. Only classnames should start with uppercase letters. Variable, method, and parameter names should all start with lowercase letters. Your function should be `func answersAndResults (answerIndex: Int, link: Dictionary <Int, Int>)`. Following the standards makes your code easier to read by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift dictionaries are value types, so when you pass them into functions as parameters, the function is receiving a `let` *copy* of the dictionary. If you want the function to modify the original dictionary you pass in, you have to make it an `inout` parameter. This will copy the result of any changes you make in the function back out to the original dictionary var.

The second point to remember is that inside your for loop, you are also getting an immutable *copy* of each key and value (since they are Ints, which are also value types, not reference types), so you need to set the new value on the original dictionary, not just try to increment the copy inside the loop.

Combining the points above, you can change your function to something like this:

```
func answersAndResults (answerIndex: Int, link: inout [Int:Int]) {
    if inputIndex == answerIndex {
        for (linkedResult, weight) in link {
            link[linkedResult] == linkedResult + weight
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that `[Int:Int]` is a more conventional Swift shorthand for `Dictionary<Int, Int>`.